# has_and_belongs_to_many and foreign_key does not work in Rails Admin + MongoID

Tags: mongoid, rails-admin

I am using Rails 5, Rails Admin and MongoId, In my model, I added

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :topics, class_name: 'Topic', :foreign_key => :topicIds
```

It works with 'edit page', but does not work when i try to change the value of topicIds

```
message: Attempted to set a value for 'topic_ids' which is not allowed on the model AppUser. summary: Without including Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic in your model and the attribute does not already exist in the attributes hash, attempting to call AppUser#topic_ids= for it is not allowed. This is also triggered by passing the attribute to any method that accepts an attributes hash, and is raised instead of getting a NoMethodError. resolution: You can include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic if you expect to be writing values for undefined fields often.
```

It means that MongoId does not fully understand ':foreign_key'. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by add an alias field to the model:

```
field :topicIds, type: Array, :as => :topic_ids
```